# jQuery adding numeric input dynamically

Tags: jquery, input, numbers, row, addition

I have this code:

```
switch (newcell.childNodes[1].type)
{
    case "text":
        newcell.childNodes[1].value = "";
        break;
    case "number":
        newcell.childNodes[1].value = "";
        break;
    case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[1].selectedIndex = 0;
        break;
```

This is a little piece of code for an add/delete row functionality I'm making. The row contains inputs.

Well, I manage to generate new raw with all inputs except this one:

```
<td><input type="number" /></td>
```

I think the issue is here: `case "number":`. How do I make reference in my JS to the `type="number"` input?

**ADDING MORE INFO**

My HTML code:

```
 <tbody id="dataTable">                       
        <tr class="trBody">
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="FeeClass" runat="server" name="feeClass">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" value=""/></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="numberInput" value=""/></td>
            <td><button onclick="deleteRow(this)">Remove</button></td>
        </tr>  
 </tbody>
```

My JS code:

```
function addRow(dataTable) {

    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.id = row.uniqueID;
    row.id = "row" + rowCount;
    var rowID = row.id;
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {

        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        if (i == colCount-1){
            newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute('id', "rB" + rowCount);
        }
        newcell.childNodes[1].name = newcell.childNodes[1].id + rowCount;

        //alert(newcell.childNodes);
        switch (newcell.childNodes[1].type)
        {
            case "text":
                newcell.childNodes[1].value = "";
                break;
            case "number":
                newcell.childNodes[1].value = "";
                break;
            case "select-one":
                newcell.childNodes[1].selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

It generates the new row and stops at the number input. Genrates the dropdown, the text input and stops...

Answer (score 0):

use typeof(newcell.childNodes[1]) instead newcell.childNodes[1].type

Comment: I will try it. (Having some problems with server at the moment). I just updated post with more info if needed.

Comment: I tried, and didn't work. I mean, it works with text inputs, but didn't work with the number input.. Maybe is stopping there of some other reason. But the same script is working for another table (with same id number and structure but without number input).